# A condition when two sums equal

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

I have looked for an answer to this, but could not figure out a proof.  Does the following hold:

If $\sum _{k = 0}^{p }a_k*y_k = \sum_{k=0}^{p }b_k*y_k$, then $$\sum _{k = 0}^{p }a_k = \sum_{k=0}^{p }b_k$$.

Any counterexamples or proofs would be much appreciated.

I can prove something interesting if this general case holds.

Comment: Must hold for all $y_k$? Or one specific $y_k$?

Comment: I would like to know if the if..then condition holds for all $y_k$.

Comment: Are you talking about integers, rational, or what else? I see "real analysis" tag

Comment: for integers $a_k$,$b_k$ and rational $y_k$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sum _{k = 0}^{p }a_k\,y_k $$
is the dot product of the vector ${\bf{a}} = (a_0,a_1,\cdots,a_p)$ with the vector ${\bf y}=(y_0,\cdots,y_p)$.
Similarly for the RHS.

If the equality holds for $p+1$ independent different vectors $\bf y^{(0)}, y^{(1)}, \cdots,y^{(p)}$, having components not totally null, then these vectors represent a basis of $R^{p+1}$, and 
$$\sum _{k = 0}^{p }a_k\,y^{(j)}_k  \quad|\; j=0\cdots p$$ 
are the components of $\bf a$ in that basis, and two vectors with the same components in a given basis of their space, have the same components in any other basis, i.e. are equal.

That premised, then it depends on how you want to use the "if .. then" construction.

It is clear that 
$$\sum _{k = 0}^{p }a_k = \sum_{k=0}^{p }b_k$$
means that the two vectors have the same dot product with the vector $(1,1, \cdots,1)$, i.e. that the corresponding points lie  on the same diagonal plane  $x_0+x_1+\cdots+x_p=d$. And that can be, without that they need to be equal.

Comment: This is great!  I got it.  Thank you.

Comment: glad that my answer was of  help (then you might consider to mark it as accepted).

Comment: I will and I am going to cite it in my proposed draft for publication.  Thank you again.

Comment: G Cab does it necessarily follow that a and b are equal?

Comment: @AveryCarr, I have expanded my answer: don't know how much familiar you are with vector spaces, nor what exactly is your final goal.

Comment: Thank you.  I am familiar with vector spaces, but I do need to think of this a little more as it is being applied to a number theory problem.  What if the $y_k=\binom{p+1}{k}B_k$ where $B_k$ are Bernoulli numbers of the second kind?

Answer (score 0):

If you meant that for a specific $y_k$ the condition holds, then let $y_k = 0$ and any $a_k, b_k$ with different sums form a counterexample.

If instead you meant that the condition is valid for *all* $y_k$, then it must hold for $y_k = 1$ and therefore the conclusion is valid.